# SpringJPA please suggest custom query for

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Can you suggest a custom query for

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM ngb.payment_bifurcation AS p1
WHERE p1.bill_id = 13528 And exists  ( SELECT *
        FROM ngb.payment AS p2
          WHERE p2.deleted = false and p1.payment_id = p2.id
      )
```

`bill_id` is a parameter.

Comment: Consider providing more details like Entity models, etc. Question like this without details would not attract people who are willing to help.

Comment: What is the problem with the query you have?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create a native query for this. Standard Data JPA methods might not help.